# Possibilities to improve performance using vectorization for the following function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vectorization, system.numerics

I have a function that estimates correlation between two input arrays.

The input is feeded by a `dataDict` which is of type `Dictionary<string, double[]>` which has 153 keys with values as double array of size 1500.

For each individual key, I need to estimate its correlation with all other keys and store the result to a `double[,]` that has a size of `double[dataDict.Count(), dataDict.Count()]`

The following function prepares two `double[]` arrays whose correlation needs to be estimated.

```
public double[,] CalculateCorrelation(Dictionary<string, double?[]> dataDict, string corrMethod = "kendall")
        {
            CorrelationLogicModule correlationLogicModule = new CorrelationLogicModule();
            double[,] correlationMatrix = new double[dataDict.Count(), dataDict.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataDict.Count; i++)
            {                
                for (int j = 0; j < dataDict.Count; j++)
                {
                    var arrayA = dataDict[dataDict.ElementAt(i).Key].Cast<double>().ToArray();
                    var arrayB = dataDict[dataDict.ElementAt(j).Key].Cast<double>().ToArray();
                    correlationMatrix[i, j] = correlationLogicModule.Kendall_Formula(arrayA, arrayB);
                }
            }
            return correlationMatrix;
        }
```

The following function (I found it on internet from [here](https://github.com/Mith0304/CorrelEstimator/blob/master/Kendall)) finds correlation between two input arrays using 'Kendall's' method.

```
public double Kendall_Formula(double[] Ticker1, double[] Ticker2)
        {
            double NbrConcord, NbrDiscord, S;
            NbrConcord = 0;
            NbrDiscord = 0;
            S = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Ticker1.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < Ticker1.Length; j++)
                {
                    //Compute the number of concordant pairs
                    if (((Ticker1[i] < Ticker1[j]) & (Ticker2[i] < Ticker2[j])) | ((Ticker1[i] > Ticker1[j]) & (Ticker2[i] > Ticker2[j])))
                    {
                        NbrConcord++;
                    }
                    //Compute the number of discordant pairs
                    else if (((Ticker1[i] > Ticker1[j]) & (Ticker2[i] < Ticker2[j])) | ((Ticker1[i] < Ticker1[j]) & (Ticker2[i] > Ticker2[j])))
                    {
                        NbrDiscord++;
                    }
                }
            }
            S = NbrConcord - NbrDiscord;
            //Proportion with the total pairs
            return 2 * S / (Ticker1.Length * (Ticker1.Length - 1));
        }
```

Moving this way forward, takes a very long time to calculate the correlations for all the keys.
is there a possible way to optimize the performance?.

I am new to C# but I have been using Python for a long time and in Python using 'Numpys' and 'Pandas' I am sure the above operation would take seconds to compute. For e.g. lets say I had the above data in form of a pandas dataframe, then `data[[list of columns]].corr('method')` would lead the result in seconds. This is because pandas uses numpy under the hood which takes benefit from vectorization. I would like to learn how can I take benefit from vectorization to improve the performance of the above code in C# and if there are other factors I need to consider. Thank you!

Comment: If you use the short-circuiting logical operators `&&` and `||` instead of the bitwise operators `&` and `|`, you might improve the speed.

Comment: Does your computer have a GPU that supports OpenCL or CUDA?

Comment: You should change the bitwise `&` to logical `&&` in your conditions. The use of `&` will prevent the compiler applying a boolean short-circuit optimisation, meaning that all the `<`/`>` comparisons will be performed, even if the first condition is false.

Comment: Accessing dictionary elements using `ElementAt()` is *very* slow. You'll get more benefit from improving the inefficient code than vectorizing it

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what `dataDict[dataDict.ElementAt(i).Key]` is doing... Not only is this an O(N) operation, the order in which the items will be returned is unspecified.

Comment: Note that the `.ElementAt()` call is a Linq extension, not a member of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. It iterates from the start of the dictionary EVERY TIME you call it. And it returns items in an unspecified order. From the documentation: `For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `dataDict[dataDict.ElementAt(i).Key]` to access the dictionary values in an undefined order. I don't know if that's what you intended, but the following code should give the the same results.

If you call `dataDict.Values.ToArray();` you will get the dictionary values in the same order as you would when using `foreach` to iterate over it. That means that it will be the same as the order when using `dataDict[dataDict.ElementAt(i).Key]`.

Therefore this code should be equivalent, and it should be faster:

```
public double[,] CalculateCorrelation(Dictionary<string, double?[]> dataDict, string corrMethod = "kendall")
{
    CorrelationLogicModule correlationLogicModule = new CorrelationLogicModule();

    var values = dataDict.Values.Select(array => array.Cast<double>().ToArray()).ToArray();

    double[,] correlationMatrix = new double[dataDict.Count, dataDict.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataDict.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataDict.Count; j++)
        {
            var arrayA = values[i];
            var arrayB = values[j];
            correlationMatrix[i, j] = correlationLogicModule.Kendall_Formula(arrayA, arrayB);
        }
    }
    return correlationMatrix;
}
```

Note that the `.ElementAt()` call in your original code is a Linq extension, not a member of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. It iterates from the start of the dictionary EVERY TIME you call it - and it also returns items in an unspecified order. From the documentation: `For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.`

---

Also:

You should change the bitwise `&` to logical `&&` in your conditions. The use of `&` will prevent the compiler applying a boolean short-circuit optimisation, meaning that all the `<` / `>` comparisons will be performed, even if the first condition is false.

Comment: Mind: The Dictionary is actually `Dictionary<string, double?[]>` and OP's Kendall method is expecting `double[]` ...

Comment: @Fildor Lemme double check that!

Comment: Hey thanks, that does improve the performance significantly from ~4 min to ~2min but still a lot slower than the python version.

Comment: @Fildor Fixed that, but of course there will be a runtime exception if any of the values in the original `double?` arrays are null - but that will also happen in the original code.